# i am unable to make any artisian command...whenever i run a commad it says unable to load php mbstring.so 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library `php5.6-mbstring.so`

> (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/php5.6-mbstring.so
>   (/usr/lib/php/20170718/php5.6-mbstring.so: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory),
>   /usr/lib/php/20170718/php5.6-mbstring.so.so
>   (/usr/lib/php/20170718/php5.6-mbstring.so.so: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line

Comment: i disabled mbstring stop php5.6 also....but the error is same

Comment: this extension is required by laravel

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.6 will not run on php5.6 you need these requirements

```
PHP >= 7.1.3
OpenSSL PHP Extension
PDO PHP Extension
Mbstring PHP Extension
Tokenizer PHP Extension
XML PHP Extension
Ctype PHP Extension
JSON PHP Extension
```

More over if this is really a pain to setup the development environment then you can try Homestead

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6#installation